# How to understand the annotation @ComponentScan work when wiring Bean without application.xml?

Tags: spring, ioc-container, component-scan

1, When my dictionary tree likes these, the error "@EnableAsync annotation metadata was not injected" occurs。

[image]
[image]

2, But when my dictionary tree likes this, the error doesn't happen.

[image]

3, When I wire Bean with application.xml, and the dictionary tree likes paragraph one, but the error also doesn't happen.

[image]

So what I am so confirmed is that @ComponentScan's work when wiring Bean without application.xml?

Comment: Please don't add code as images, as those are totally unreadable.

Answer (score 3):

> When a class does not include a package declaration, it is considered to be in the “default package” (src.main.java). The use of
> the “default package” is generally discouraged and should be avoided.
> It can cause particular problems for Spring Boot applications that use
> the @ComponentScan, @ConfigurationPropertiesScan, @EntityScan, or
> @SpringBootApplication annotations, since every class from every jar
> is read.
>
> Spring Boot favors Java-based configuration. Although it is possible
> to use SpringApplication with XML sources, we generally recommend that
> your primary source be a single @Configuration class. Usually the
> class that defines the main method is a good candidate as the primary
> @Configuration.

This is a classic bug when first making a spring application, it is better to have all your classes in a package, never put your classes in the "default" (src.main.java) package.

Read more here from chapter "2. Structuring Your Code" to "3. Configuration Classes":

> https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-configuration-classes